# How to loop over data in a UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, loops, foreach

I’m using Alamofire Library for http request.

I know how to loop in plain text field:

```
for option in json["options"] {
    let opts = json["options"]["is_selected"].string

    if json["options"][ctr]["is_selected"] == 1 {
        if json["options"][ctr]["id"] == "8" {
            self.emailSwitch.on = true
            self.unameSwitch.on = true
         }
     }
     println(json["options"][ctr]["id"])
     ctr++
 }
```

But how do I do it in a table view?

Comment: what do you want to loop where? you want to loop *inside* a tableview? What should that do?

Comment: Do you want to loop the UITableViewCells in the UITableView?

Comment: @luk2302 yes i want to loop UITableViewCells in a tableview

Comment: Read up on how UITableViews work. The question is too broad to answer and you would at least need a basic understanding of how they work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I can help if you provide direction for your question.

Comment: You are trying to loop the cells!? the created ones or do you want to specify the cells content? it is really unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Chackle hi chackle, i dont actually know the names and terms in xcode. i want to display the names in a table. that means we have to loop the datas. that i do not know where to start. can you provide me a simple code?

Comment: @luk2302  I want to loop different data into each row.

Comment: you should really take a look how tableviews work, what the datasource and the delegate are there for and how to use them.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the uitableview like this:

```
for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections() {

    for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(section) {

       let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
       var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) 

       // do what you want with the cell

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can loop throgh the cells which are currently visible:

```
let indexpaths = indexPathsForVisibleRows()!
    let totalVisibleCells = indexpaths.count - 1
    if totalVisibleCells <= 0 { return }

    for index in 0...totalVisibleCells {
        let indexPath = indexpaths[index] as! NSIndexPath
        if let cell = cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {

              // Do your cell modifications here...

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.2

```
 for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {

                for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(section) {

                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
                    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

                    // do what you want with the cell

                }
            }
```